# I can't update the database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that use SQL Server and EF Core. It contains two tables. I successfully created an Entity Framework Core migration and updated the database with it for the first table called `Pies`.

Then after I added another table called `Feedbacks`, I created a second migration.

However, when I attempt to update the database, it fails and I get this error:

> Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
>   There is already an object named 'Pies' in the database.

Here is the `DbContext` class:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Pie> Pies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything in between the steps you described? like delete previous migration files or tables in the database?

Comment: I have deleted the last migration and added it again but with same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have messed up the record history of EF Core migrations by deleting a migration file and your snapshot is tainted as well because you re-ran the migrations after deleting one.

Here are the steps you should take:

1. Delete all remaining migrations
2. Delete the database
3. Create a new initial migration
4. Create a new database.

In the future to avoid these error's use a version control system like `git`. And before creating any migrations commit. Note you will need to remove the incorrectly applied migration to your database from the `_EfMigrations` table in your database, since git doesn't version control your database.

Comment: Thanks @Anton I use git  already , so i'll return to a previous version

Comment: @SaTech if you return to the previous version make sure to follow the last step I mention and remove the previously applied migrations to the database. EXCEPT the one for pie. the id will equal to the name of the migration.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a difference between the data in the database table and the files in the database.

You most likely created the database once and then deleted the migraine folder

Comment: Thanks @Reza  yes the Feedback table doesn't appear in the database when I view it in the SQL Server Object Explorer